# Cannot write / edit over ftp using vsftpd centos 7?

Tags: linux, ftp, centos7

Wondering if anyone can help, I have vsftpd setup on my server and I can view, download and access all files but I can't edit, upload or create any new files / folders.

I have checked permissions and put selinux into permissive mode but still can't write.

Here's my vsftpd.conf Could I possible be doing something wrong that won't allow me to write?

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
# When SELinux is enforcing check for SE bool ftp_home_dir
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
# When SELinux is enforcing check for SE bool allow_ftpd_anon_write,     allow_ftpd_full_access
anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do  ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses.  Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
chroot_local_user=YES
# chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
# chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
listen_ipv6=YES

local_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

pasv_enable=YES

guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp

anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_umask=022

local_root=/srv/www/
```

the log file,

```
Thu Mar 19 14:43:58 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /stolenmx.com b _ o r  stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 14:44:04 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /stolenmx.com b _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 14:44:28 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /stolenmx.com b _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 14:51:20 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 20698  /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/colours.css a _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 14:53:25 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 14:54:30 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:06:38 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /stolenmx.com b _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:14:55 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667  /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o r stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:15:23 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:15:53 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:16:04 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:17:28 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i r stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:26:03 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:26:13 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:27:32 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g luke ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:27:59 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g luke ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:28:42 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:28:47 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:29:45 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:29:51 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:30:13 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:30:53 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/test.php a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:31:48 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:31:55 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 15:36:21 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 667 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 15:36:26 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
Thu Mar 19 16:12:34 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 2005 /forum/install_forum_goal.php a _ o g stolenftp ftp 0 * c
Thu Mar 19 16:12:45 2015 1 ::ffff:78.47.143.141 0 /forum/install_forum_goal.php a _ i g stolenftp ftp 0 * i
```

Comment: Can you share some logs or the errors you are getting?

Comment: Not sure where to find them?

Comment: Check out /var/log/vsftpd.log

Comment: Don't have a log file with that name, could only fined xfer.log which i have added to the original comment.

Comment: Add this to add more logging. `Default: /var/log/vsftpd.log`

Comment: vsftpd fails to restart with that line. Are you sure that's the correct syntax?

Comment: Sorry its `vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log`.  Make sure the file exists as well. `touch /var/log/vsftpd.log`

Comment: Hey bud, just tried this and the log is empty. It doesn't add anything.

Comment: in the ftp client it says the files and folders are writable but when trying it just says unable to write to directory.

Comment: What directory on the server are you writing to?  What are the permissions on the directory?  What user is vsftpd running as?

Comment: Directory is /srv/www (wordpress) the permissions are 644 for files and 755 for folders and I'm connecting as a new user which I just added, vsftpd is running on root I believe. I tried changing the whole directory to 777 dangerous I know, but just to test and it had no effect.

Comment: Try creating a file server side, `/srv/www/test.txt` set the permissions to 777 for that file.  Upload a new file `test.txt` to overwrite it and see what happens.

Comment: well that worked =) (File test.txt has been transferred to the FTP server using FTP mode FTP_ASCII) which is strange because I changed the whole directory to 777 earlier and it didn't work. Let me try something else real quick. Think it may just be a phpbb issue as It's phpbb I'm trying to access over ftp.

Comment: Okay that worked too so perhaps I didn't make the whole directory 777. SO now the question sis it only allows me to write / edit with 777 is this safe or is there another way?

Comment: Okay so when i set the whole directory to 777 I can't even login to ftp... SOooo confused.

Answer (score 0):

The directory needs to be 777.  Make sure to set the umask as well.  I would highly encourage you not to run vsftpd as root, run it as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Okay so you mean login as a new user and start vsftpd from there?

I just tried to change the directory to 777 and couldn't login to ftp from any account.

Comment: Yeah it can only run in root. Still messing with it. The issue now is I can't access FTP at all when the directory is set to 777. I have no idea what to do now. setting perms to 777 is the only way to have full access over FTP but I can't connect. =(

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for 777 as it is not secure.

Here is the checklist -

1) Check the ownership of directory. Check the group of ftp user you are trying to connect, lets say if direcoties ownership belongs to a different group, then there could be problem. The ftp user should be in same group whose ownership is set on directory.

2) Check the umasking as well if umasking is 002 then all the user and group will have all the access.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the puzzle is to allow selinux to access the directory.

You can either disable selinux or set the permissions

On my system in /var/log/messages it gave the instruction:

setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1

This worked. The full message in /var/log/messages was:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/vsftpd from create access on the file backupedge.txt.0.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (47.5 confidence) suggests   ******************#012#012If you want to allow ftp to home dir#012Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'ftp_home_dir' boolean.#012#012Do#012setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (47.5 confidence) suggests   ******************#012#012If you want to allow ftpd to full access#012Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'ftpd_full_access' boolean.#012#012Do#012setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (6.38 confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that vsftpd should be allowed create access on the backupedge.txt.0 file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#0